# python if __name__ == "__main__": IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python, python-unittest

I use PyCharm to right click Run 'hello ' or use shell to run  python hello.py ,both return below error :

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
                             ^ 
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

below code is copied from https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class TestHello(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            "D:\\Softwares\\selenium\\ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")

    def test_pick_goods(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.send_keys("pycon")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
        print("-----last line----")

    def tearDown(self):
        #self.driver.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I used tab or four whitespaces before if **name** == "**main**",but both have no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is coming from the empty method above:

```
def tearDown(self):
    #self.driver.close()
```

You can't have a completely empty method, the parser can't handle it. Add a `pass` statement to get it to parse:

```
def tearDown(self):
    pass
```